# FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, xml

При попытке запустить приложение после компеляции, у меня выдает вот такую вот ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста, что это, не могу разобраться хоть убей.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.tstudio24.allgdznew, PID: 15709
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tstudio24.allgdznew/com.tstudio24.allgdznew.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
     at com.tstudio24.allgdznew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
     at com.tstudio24.allgdznew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v19/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:796)
     at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
     at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
     at com.tstudio24.allgdznew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2610)
     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:796) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44) 
     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254) 
     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
     at com.tstudio24.allgdznew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5277) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2322) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2410) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5395) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.inmobi.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:xlargeScreens ="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.inmobi.ads.InMobiBanner
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        ads:placementId="1457840673666"
        ads:refreshInterval="60"
    />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561235/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-toolbar

Comment: Там человек сам решил проблему, у него было много чего внедрено в проект, и он просто вернул первую версию программы, и все заработало! Там нет толкового решения проблемы к сожалению.

Comment: Судя по логу - проблема в разметке, а именно в какой-то картинке. Приложите, что ли, разметку.

Comment: Приложил к главному посту разметку...

Comment: Проблема в `res/drawable-v19/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml`: **XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector**, Если у вас аналогичные проекты, сравните эту xml с ними

Comment: Дак у меня не где в разметке нету такого!! Вот в чем вся суть.